# How to reset the react form input value (which is tied to a state) with a button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

How to reset the react form input value (which is tied to a state) with a button?

```
<Form.Group controlId="availabilityOborotDoc">
  <Form.Label>Documents</Form.Label>
  <Form.Control
    type="number"
    name="availabilityOborotDoc"
    required
    readOnly
    value={this.state.settings.availabilityOborotDoc}
  />
  <Link
    to={{
      pathname: `/ost-docs`,
      state: {
        settings: this.state.settings,
        isSelectDoc: true,
        isEdit: isEdit,
        isCreate: isCreate
      }
    }}
  >
    <Button variant="primary" disabled={isView}>
      Choose document
    </Button>
  </Link>
  <Button
    variant="warning"
    disabled={isView}
    onClick={() => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        settings: {
          ...prevState.settings,
          availabilityOborotDoc: null
        }
      }));
      this.forceUpdate();
    }}
  >
    Reset
  </Button>
</Form.Group>;
```

The Reset button I implemented clears the state field allright but doesn't set the value in input... (apparently it remembers the previous one)

Comment: Why are you calling `forceUpdate`?

Comment: where is the state defined?

Comment: I tried it as one measure but it doesn't work... What will work though?

Comment: @mmenschig this is a long component, it is just a part. State is as always in the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the state to an empty string instead of `null` and it will work.

Check out [this link](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11417) for a little more explanation (at least it seems relevant?). My assumption is that because react treats an input with `null` value as uncontrolled, it will leave the current value.

Here is a simplified example:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      settings: {
        availabilityOborotDoc: '12345'
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
  console.log(this.state.settings)
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          readOnly
          value={this.state.settings.availabilityOborotDoc}
        />
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
              settings: {
                ...prevState.settings,
                availabilityOborotDoc: ''
              }
            }));
          }}
        >
          Reset
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
          
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Thank You!!! It works! Why does this behave like that though? Any knowledge will be appreciated

Comment: I added a bit more to my answer. I believe that's why, but I can't prove it. I just know that react complains when you assign an input a `null` value, so I figured there was a good bet that was the issue.